# Logging on Debian (squeeze) broken

Tags: debian, logging

I just noticed that the logging system is broken on my debian machine, syslog is empty and nothing is begin added into the syslog.

I need to fix this, but where do I start ?

What would cause this ?

syslog-ng config seems to be fine and syslog-ng process is running, disks are not full and folders are correct.

```
/var/log > ps -ef | grep syslog
root      1463     1  0 Aug01 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --pid-file /var/run/mdadm/monitor.pid --daemonise --scan --syslog
root     15495 15482  0 18:06 pts/7    00:00:00 tail -f syslog
root     15729     1  0 18:17 ?        00:00:00 supervising syslog-ng                        
root     15730 15729  0 18:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -p /var/run/syslog-ng.pid


cat /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
@version: 3.1
#
# Syslog-ng configuration file, compatible with default Debian syslogd
# installation. Originally written by anonymous (I can't find his name)
# Revised, and rewrited by me (SZALAY Attila <sasa@debian.org>)

# First, set some global options.
options { long_hostnames(off); flush_lines(0); use_dns(no); use_fqdn(no);
      owner("root"); group("adm"); perm(0640); stats_freq(600);
      bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
};

########################
# Sources
########################
# This is the default behavior of sysklogd package
# Logs may come from unix stream, but not from another machine.
#
source s_src { unix-dgram("/dev/log"); internal();
             file("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel"));
};

# If you wish to get logs from remote machine you should uncomment
# this and comment the above source line.
#
#source s_net { tcp(ip(127.0.0.1) port(1000) authentication(required) encrypt(allow)); };

########################
# Destinations
########################
# First some standard logfile
#
destination d_auth { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
destination d_cron { file("/var/log/cron.log"); };
destination d_daemon { file("/var/log/daemon.log"); };
destination d_kern { file("/var/log/kern.log"); };
destination d_lpr { file("/var/log/lpr.log"); };
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/mail.log"); };
destination d_syslog { file("/var/log/syslog"); };
destination d_user { file("/var/log/user.log"); };
destination d_uucp { file("/var/log/uucp.log"); };

# This files are the log come from the mail subsystem.
#
destination d_mailinfo { file("/var/log/mail/mail.info"); };
destination d_mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail/mail.warn"); };
destination d_mailerr { file("/var/log/mail/mail.err"); };
```

Comment: Is your syslog service running?

Comment: yea it's running

Comment: syslog-ng service is running, disk is not full, rights on the dirs are normal (compared to another debian squeeze machine)

Comment: Please give us the output of `ps -ef | grep syslog` and `cat /etc/syslog.conf`?

Comment: We use syslog-ng btw, output will be placed in comment by Lucas. Config file for syslog-ng is /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems for some reason the config file lost its filters and destinations in the syslog-ng.conf file. Altering the file to a default dpkg package file worked.

Thx for all the suggestions.

Comment: thank you goez I wish we had you on our server team *cough*